# RSA Encryption Failing on just the iPhone 4s running iOS 9

Tags: ios, rsa, swift4, xcode9.2

I am successfully `RSA-Encrypting` a string but when i do it on iPhone 4s (iOS 9.3.2) it fails and returns `'nil'` as a result. However it is successfully working on all the other iphones(5,6,7,8,X.)

I am using this RSA Public-Key:

> "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQClTlHEResIvOPHR0+o4exJVEI5RQ4NnBBXV9tdoCbqavSgsiuFtZWn5RUVTLb0h7ULpOh8GDcu0yI4lnpMVDZ5U2w0ra2/BNl6XDt9bwwoOh5w2lsdVmdP94t/qVBX4C0OcXw+RdSD1pshucTO7m2YLxtzLuc4ChUwjWZXVEoHdQIDAQAB"

It is actually on this line of code where i am getting &keyRef 'nil'

```
err = SecItemCopyMatching(dictionary as CFDictionary, &keyRef);
```

Here is my code;

```
func encryptString(stringToEncrypt:String) -> String {
    print("stringToEncrypt64 = " + stringToEncrypt)

    let keyData = NSData(base64Encoded: Constants.RSA_Public_Key, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)

    let dictionary: [NSString: AnyObject] = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: "HBLMobilePublicKeyTag" as AnyObject,
        kSecValueData: keyData!,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 1024),
        kSecReturnRef: true as AnyObject
    ];

    var err = SecItemAdd(dictionary as CFDictionary, nil);

    if ((err != noErr) && (err != errSecDuplicateItem)) {
        print("error loading public key");
    }

    var keyRef: AnyObject?;
    var base64String: String?
    err = SecItemCopyMatching(dictionary as CFDictionary, &keyRef);
    if (err == noErr) {
        if let keyRef = keyRef as! SecKey? {

            let plaintextLen = stringToEncrypt.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
            let plaintextBytes = [UInt8](stringToEncrypt.utf8);

            var encryptedLen: Int = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef);
            var encryptedBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: encryptedLen);

            err = SecKeyEncrypt(keyRef, SecPadding.PKCS1, plaintextBytes, plaintextLen, &encryptedBytes, &encryptedLen);
            let data = NSData(bytes: encryptedBytes, length: encryptedBytes.count)

            base64String = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        }
    }

    SecItemDelete(dictionary as CFDictionary);
    return base64String!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's that the iPhone 4s is out of date. If the versions are the same like all phones on ios-9 then it could be the hardware on the phone. Or it could be that you don't have enough space to store the application on the phone for it to work. It could be that half the files are on the phone and that it says `Completed Transfer` When it didn't complete it.

Sorry, I'm just saying what I know (Which I know nothing about IPhones) about software.

Comment: but when i use a different public key, it works fine on all iOS devices, strange. There is something missing in the key which iOS 9 is expecting.

Comment: sorry, like I said i'm not to sure. I'm just suggesting ideas. Sorry